# Getting a refined type by matching a member value corresponding to a type member

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-members

I have a container for heterogeneous types

```
trait Elem

trait Obj {
  type E <: Elem
  def elem: E
}

trait Foo extends Elem
```

There should not be any sub-classes of `Obj`. I am looking for suggestions as how to elegantly match an instance of `Obj` against a number of element types to gain a refined `Obj`.

For example:

```
def withFooObj(obj: Obj { type E = Foo }) = ()

def test(obj: Obj): Unit = obj.elem match {
  case f: Foo =>
    withFooObj(obj.asInstanceOf[Obj { type E = Foo }]) // !
  case _ =>
}
```

What would be an elegant idea to get rid of the cast? Ideally it would work as a pattern match.

---

For example, I can create individual extractors:

```
object IsFoo {
  def unapply(obj: Obj): Option[Obj { type E = Foo }] =
    if (obj.elem.isInstanceOf[Foo]) Some(obj.asInstanceOf[Obj { type E = Foo }])
    else None
}

def test(obj: Obj): Unit = obj match {
  case IsFoo(x) => withFooObj(x)
  case _ =>
}
```

But I have many sub-types of `Elem` and would prefer to have a generic extractor.

---

**Edit:** Since this seems to be a tough one, I want to add another relaxation: It is allowed to change `Obj` to contain a type parameter instead of a type member (if it helps). It is *not* allowed to require sub-classes of `Obj`.

Comment: The more I look at these problems, to more I have the idea the dynamically typed languages ultimately succeed when it comes to representing collections of heterogeneous data (not known at compile time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect this to be impossible. Consider (assuming `class Foo extends Elem`)

```
val obj1 = new Obj {
  type E = Elem
  def elem = new Foo
}
```

Since `obj.elem` does match `f: Foo`, but `obj1` doesn't actually have type `Obj { type E = Foo }`, you do have to cast. <s>This cast is actually safe in this case, but only because `Obj` doesn't have e.g. any methods *taking* `E`.</s> Actually, it isn't safe, since the value of the *first* call to `elem` having class `Foo` doesn't mean *all* calls to `elem` will return `Foo`.

EDIT: if you are all right with merely hiding the cast in the extractor, you may be able to do something like this:

```
case class IsElem[T <: Elem]()(implicit ct: ClassTag[T]) {
  def unapply(obj: Obj): Option[Obj { type E = T }] =
    if (ct.runtimeClass.isInstance(obj.elem)) Some(obj.asInstanceOf[Obj { type E = T }])
      else None
}

val IsFoo = IsElem[Foo]
val IsBar = IsElem[Bar]
...
```

EDIT2: with type parameters, you can do

```
(obj, obj.elem) match {
  case (obj: Obj[Foo] @unchecked, f: Foo) => ...
  case (obj: Obj[Bar] @unchecked, f: Bar) => ...
}
```

Obviously, this doesn't help safety issues.

Comment: Ok, but can I hide the cast away in some extractor function? After all pattern matching is using "safe" casts all the time.

Comment: I had a similiar idea, but gave up when I couldn't do `case IsElem[Foo](x) => ...` in one go. Storing them as `val`s of course is nice idea, so there is no additional performance tax.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Actually the contract is that `Elem` is stable, I could as well define it as a `val`. The `@unchecked` is ok, but not good in use-site code. I'll go with something similar to the `IsElem` extractor.

Answer (score 0):

(Here I wanted to be clever:)

```
trait Idea {
  def resolve[A](obj: Obj)
      (f: Function1[(Obj { type E = E1 }, E1) forSome { type E1 <: Elem }, A]): A
}

def test(obj: Obj, idea: Idea): Unit = idea.resolve(obj) {
  case (x, _: Foo) => withFooObj(x)
  case _ =>
}
```

But Scalac doesn't think that `E1 == Foo` here...

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to focus on your requirement for a heterogeneous container, and ignore certain details like the type member, and pattern matching.

**Summary**

The goal is to have some way to process an `Obj` based on its `elem` type. The important parts of the working solution:

- Make `Obj` an abstract class taking a type parameter representing `elem`.
- Automatically associate a `Processor` parameterized on the same type as `elem`, by using an implicit parameter.
- Define implicit `Processor`s for all the `Elem` types you want to use.

I consider defining the implicit `Processor`s as minimal boilerplate (if you can actually call it boilerplate). You need to defined `elem`-specific processors anyway, so these implicit objects are a good place to organize them.

**The code:**

```
trait Elem {
  // for debugging only
  def typeName: String
}

abstract class Obj[E <: Elem](implicit val processor: Processor[E]) {
  def elem: E

  def process(): Unit = processor.process(this)
}

trait Processor[R <: Elem] {
  def process(obj: Obj[R]): Unit
}
object Processor {
  implicit val fooProcessor = new Processor[Foo] {
    def process(obj: Obj[Foo]): Unit = println(s"Processing Foo: ${obj.elem.typeName}")
  }
  implicit val barProcessor = new Processor[Bar] {
    def process(obj: Obj[Bar]): Unit = println(s"Processing Bar: ${obj.elem.typeName}")
  }
  implicit val widgetProcessor = new Processor[Widget] {
    def process(obj: Obj[Widget]): Unit = println(s"Processing Widget: ${obj.elem.typeName}")
  }
}

trait Foo extends Elem { def typeName = "Foo" }
trait Bar extends Elem { def typeName = "Bar" }
trait Widget extends Elem { def typeName = "Widget" }

def test2[R <: Elem](obj: Obj[R]): Unit = obj.process()

// MAIN

val objFoo = new Obj[Foo] {
  def elem: Foo = new Foo { }
}
println("===== test2 on a static-typed Foo")
test2(objFoo)

val objBar = new Obj[Bar] {
  def elem: Bar = new Bar { }
}
println("===== test2 on a static-typed Bar")
test2(objBar)

val objWidget = new Obj[Widget] {
  def elem: Widget = new Widget { }
}
println("===== test2 on a static-typed Widget")
test2(objWidget)

println("===== test2 on a heterogeneous list of `Obj`s")
val heteroList = List(objFoo, objBar, objWidget)
heteroList.foreach(test2(_))
```

Output:

```
===== test2 on a static-typed Foo
Processing Foo: Foo
===== test2 on a static-typed Bar
Processing Bar: Bar
===== test2 on a static-typed Widget
Processing Widget: Widget
===== test2 on a heterogeneous list of `Obj`s
Processing Foo: Foo
Processing Bar: Bar
Processing Widget: Widget
```